# where are the drawings for DE 202005010768 U1

Tags: patent-figures

I'm sorry for not being clear the first time.  I have an invention that I want to patent, but it sounds similar to DE200520010768. I'm hoping that photos of diagrams of DE200520010768 will be helpful to me in figuring out whether this is what I am trying to patent so that I don't go forward with mine. The line 0010 of the patent refers to three drawings. I am trying to find out where I can see these drawings.

Thank you so much for any help you can provide, even if it is referring me elsewhere to search for the drawings themselves. I tagged this as patent-infringement because that is what I am trying to avoid.

Monica

Where are the drawings for this patent: Sex toy in shape of penis, comprising base with socket for insertion of ball shaped rear end
DE 202005010768 U1

I want to know because I am trying to patent something similar.

Comment: Google patents has patents from many sources. For US patent documents there is a link to see or download the PDF. For European patent documents you need to follow the Espacenet link. To get to the drawings from that point you need to click on the Mosaics link.

Comment: Two days ago I posted a comment explaining how to find the drawings starting from the patent's google patents site. This should be a link to the figures: http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/mosaics;jsessionid=E4C711E20F94FC3D21254F28D8F8B2D5.espacenet_levelx_prod_0?CC=DE&NR=202005010768U1&KC=U1&FT=D&ND=&date=20051006&DB=&&locale=en_EP

Comment: Thank you, George White. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The drawings you are looking for are at the following link: 
https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/mosaics?CC=DE&NR=202005010768U1&KC=U1&FT=D&ND=&date=20051006&DB=&locale=